# SwiftUI Button formatting issue (Bug?)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a button set up in `ContentView` with the modifiers: `padding`, `background`, `font` and `foregroundColor`.

[image: The preview screen]

But when it runs on the simulator, this is what happens to the button:

[image: The simulator screen]

Any idea on how to solve this? The code is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var leftDiceNo = 1
    @State var rightDiceNo = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack{
                Image("diceeLogo")
                
                Spacer()
                
                HStack{
                    DiceView(n: leftDiceNo)
                    DiceView(n: rightDiceNo)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("Roll"){
                    leftDiceNo = Int.random(in: 1...6)
                    rightDiceNo = Int.random(in: 1...6)
                }
                .padding(5.0)
                .background(Color.red)
                .font(.system(size: 45))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct DiceView: View {
    
    let n: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Image("dice\(n)")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

        static var previews: some View {

        ContentView()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a bug. By default background ignores area now if it contacts with it, so disable it explicitly, like

```
Button("Roll"){
    leftDiceNo = Int.random(in: 1...6)
    rightDiceNo = Int.random(in: 1...6)
}
.padding(5.0)
.background(Color.red, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: [])
//.background(Rectangle().fill(Color.red)) // backward compatible alternate
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why the simulator screen behaved differently than the preview screen?